# Strange error with NewWebPage - SP 2010 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I'm having a strange issue here using the NewWebPage xml command in SP 2010 Foundation. The below code works does not work

```
cls
Write-Host "Production Manager v8.0 Deployment Utility" -ForegroundColor red
Write-Host ""

#Starting the script. Lets see if we can find the configuration and map files first.
Write-Host -NoNewline "Checking for the Configuration.xml, PageMap.xml and  PageTemplate.xml files: " -ForegroundColor white
if((Test-Path "Configuration.xml") -and (Test-Path "PageMap.xml") -and (Test-Path "PageTemplate.xml"))
{
     Write-Host "FOUND" -ForegroundColor green
}
else
{
    Write-Host "NOT FOUND" -ForegroundColor red
    Write-Host "Check for the necessary files and try again."
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host ""
    exit
}

Write-Host "Reading Configuration.xml"
[xml]$Configuration = Get-Content Configuration.xml
Write-Host "Reading PageMap.xml"
[xml]$PageMap = Get-Content PageMap.xml

Write-Host "Reading from Production Manager Site:    "$Configuration.Configuration.SiteConfiguration.SiteURL



#Some variables necessary for the loop
$pageCreationLoopIterations = 0
$pageLayout = ""
$pageTitle = ""
$createPageCommand = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Method ID="0,NewWebPage"><SetList Scope="Request">' + $productionManagerLibrary.ID + '</SetList><SetVar Name="Cmd">NewWebPage</SetVar><SetVar Name="ID">New</SetVar><SetVar Name="Type">WebPartPage</SetVar><SetVar Name="WebPartPageTemplate">' + $pageLayout + '</SetVar><SetVar Name="Overwrite">true</SetVar><SetVar Name="Title">MyPage</SetVar></Method>';

#Beginning the loop
Write-Host "Running through the PageMap file"

foreach($Page in $PageMap.Pages.Page)
{
     $web = Get-SPWeb $Configuration.Configuration.SiteConfiguration.SiteURL
     $productionManagerLibrary = $web.Lists | Where { $_.Title -eq "Production Manager" }
     $pageName = if($Page.SelectSingleNode("PageName")) { $Page.PageName } else {      $Configuration.Configuration.PageConfiguration.DefaultPageName }
     $pageLayout = if($Page.SelectSingleNode("PageLayout")) { $Page.PageLayout } else { $Configuration.Configuration.PageConfiguration.DefaultPageLayout }

     Write-Host 'Creating Page ' $pageName
     $web.ProcessBatchData($createPageCommand)
```

}

But this one works just fine every time I run it:

```
$url = "http://mpm8/mpm";
$listname = "Production Manager"
$web = Get-SPWeb $url
$pagesLibrary = $web.Lists | Where { $_.Title -eq "Production Manager" }
$pageLayout = 8
$cmd = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Method ID="0,NewWebPage"><SetList Scope="Request">' + $pagesLibrary.ID + '</SetList><SetVar Name="Cmd">NewWebPage</SetVar><SetVar Name="ID">New</SetVar><SetVar Name="Type">WebPartPage</SetVar><SetVar Name="WebPartPageTemplate">' + $pageLayout + '</SetVar><SetVar Name="Overwrite">true</SetVar><SetVar Name="Title">MyPage</SetVar></Method>';
$web.ProcessBatchData($cmd)
```

I really cannot see anything different between the two scripts. The error I get running the first one is:

```
<Result ID="0,NewWebPage" Code="-2130575350">
<ErrorText>Invalid URL Parameter.

The URL provided contains an invalid Command or Value. Please check the URL again.   </ErrorText></Result>
```

Can you help me on this one? Maybe I cannot run this thing out a foreach loop? :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have set the $createPageCommand first (before the loop), then set the variables that it needs second (in the loop).

If you run this in the ISE and step through (ie debug it), you can see the variables and their values, otherwise simply emit the values of the variables to screen as you run through the loop to ensure it is setting them correctly.

So, in your example, place the $createPageCommand within the loop and after $productionManagerLibrary is set.  Then, immediately before $web.ProcessBatchData($createPageCommand) you should emit the value of $createPageCommand to ensure it is OK.

I've only eye balled this without running it, but please us know if this is the reason!